# BIP32 Extended Key to EC Private and Public Key Pair

Tags: elliptic-curves, keys, key-derivation, passwords

We are working on an application in Android using Java. In our project, we used to generate EC key pairs (of size 384 bits) using SpongyCastle - an old Android version of Bouncy Castle.

The problem we face is users losing their phones or private keys. Since we are not the only ones facing this problem, I took to the Internet for some reading.

It turns out that (please correct me if I'm wrong) a lot of crypto currencies apparently use seed phrases/mnemonics (as described in [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki)) to generate a seed from which they in turn generate *extended* keys (as described in [BIP32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki)). The algorithms used will always generate the same extended keys for the same seed (which is, I'd guess, why they're called deterministic).

I managed to find some microlibraries by [Nova Crypto](https://github.com/NovaCrypto). I am now able to generate seed phrases, seeds, and extended keys.

My question is threefold:

1. Nova Crypto seems to be a guy like you and me. Since you should never write your own crypto, I probably should not use them.Are there peer-reviewed, secure libraries for the BIP-standards?
2. If I can use the libraries, how can I derive EC 384 bit key pairs from my extended keys? Is there a way to do this, or is the concept entirely different?
3. Are seed phrases secure (enough)? Are the keys generated out of these seeds as secure as the keys I generated using SpongyCastle?

Comment: 1) Not going to review Nove's random number generator. 2) HKDF-Expand will enough if 1.

Comment: I do not want you to review his code. I rephrased the question. Are there peer-reviewed implementations of the standard?
What exactly do you mean in the last part by "will enough if 1."?

Comment: As for 1: requests for libraries are off topic. For 2: that's an implementation question, unfortunately also off topic. And for 3, I'm sure we don't know: you set the requirements and we don't know how secure your spongy-generated keys are.

Comment: Stack Exchange to a T ... I'm gonna try somewhere else.